# Symfony - The database schema is not valid (sessions)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, session, doctrine

after creating the `sessions` table as mentioned in the symfony documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/database.html an error is thrown when using the database validation console command `console doctrine:schema:validate`

the session behaviour works as expected and i have not noticed any other problems, but the validation error. the validation error still persists, even if the recommended sql statement `ALTER TABLE sessions CHANGE sess_id sess_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL;` is executed.

**Error Output**

```
Mapping
-------


 [OK] The mapping files are correct.                                                                                    


Database
--------


 [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.                                              



 The following SQL statements will be executed:

     ALTER TABLE sessions CHANGE sess_id sess_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL;
```

[Error Output (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ft5.jpg)

the way the `sessions` table is created (as described in the symfony documentation)

```
  CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `sess_id` VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `sess_data` BLOB NOT NULL,
    `sess_lifetime` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    `sess_time` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: seems weird that the database won't change varbinary to varchar ... when testing with mysql, it changes the column type ..

Comment: column type changes, but still the validation fails. i have successfully executed the recommended statement `ALTER TABLE sessions CHANGE sess_id sess_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL;` and the sess_id column is VARCHAR on the db itself. still the same error when calling the validation.

Comment: I believe I had that bug too some time, that's also about the time when I stopped blindly relying on the migration diff command ;o/ it's annoying though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync your database according to entity mappings, you can use two approaches:

1. Migrate database (recommended) `bin/console doctrine:migration:diff && bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate`
2. Force Update database: `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: yes aware of that. other db changes are not the problem. using doctrine migrations for that. only `sessions`remain invalid all the time. the db structure for the sessions table was created as described in the documentation. the recommended change statement was executed using the `doctrine:schema:update --force` command and manually, still it pops up every time when using the `doctrine:schema:validate` command

Comment: Did you try `doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` command  @StFroyd

Comment: thanks ivan for the hint! i have just executed that but without success. `console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` still shows me a statement i have executed manually and using the `--force` parameter multiple times.